# Regular expression for name with parentheses

Tags: regex, string, forms, validation

so first time trying to come up with regular expression validation and im a bit confused. User populates the 'name' section of our form like so:

```
Lastname, firstname (department).
```

but it could also be

```
 lastname-hyphenedname, firstname (some department).
```

or anything along those lines. im having a hard time finding an expression that works around parentheses and various name formats with hyphens. Anyone happen to know a quick expression for this?

Comment: Specific rules are needed in order to build an appropriate regular expression

Comment: can there be multiple hyphens? like Smith-Jones-Brown?

Comment: What about Blogs-Smith,Jane-Jen-Joe (their-dept)?

Comment: Let's not forget names like `O'Brien`, `deLacey` and `McDonald`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^([A-Za-z]+([-']?|\s+))*[A-Za-z]+,\s*([A-Za-z]+([-']?|\s+))*[A-Za-z]+\s*(\([A-Za-z\s]+\))?$`

Name which may contain one or more a hyphen parts or parts separated by spaces or ', then comma, maybe some spaces, then an first-name (maybe with hyphens or spaces or '), maybe some spaces, then (name with spaces in brackets). PCRE.

Comment: i think you mean `\s` not `\S`

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I've had 0 experience with regular expressions and our forms take a somewhat interesting structure, couldnt find a guide online that i could understand well enough.

Comment: Though what if its 'lastname middlename, firstname (dept branch)' it works if theres a hpyhen but fails if theres a space between last and middle @gamag... .THanks again!

Comment: edited to allow any number of spaces between last and middle name.

Answer (score 0):

With pcre regex, you can do this:

```
^(?i)([a-z]+(?:[ '-][a-z]+)*), (?1) \([^)]+\)\.$
```

But you can be more restrictive.